# vertically center text without knowing if it will have 2 lines or one

Tags: html, css

Any idea how I can vertically center text which can have one or two lines? More over, the text has it's line-height set. I've tried [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/6rtxbxe3/) but it didn't work:

```
<div>
    <span>some text here</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>some</span>
</div>

div {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: this should help http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `display: table-cell` trick with `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    display: table;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div> <span>some text here</span>

</div>
<div> <span>some</span>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks, somehow it completely slipped off my mind)